# Story about a statue in a basement

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, aliens

I am looking for what I believe is a short story.

A summary for the plot had to do with a statue of some sorts in I think a basement, the desert, or on an alien planet. The statue had some sort of weird symbol on its chest. I think aliens were involved. I know it was in an anthology of sci-fi short stories and that it was mentioned in my science book from middle school.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This might help you to improve your question: [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/102999)

Comment: How will you know if the answer is correct based on what you have posted? Surely you know more than this.

Comment: Do you remember any more about the mention in your high school science book? What specific science subject, or why the story was being mentioned?